# Calling API from Https website to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, php, https, http, aws-ec2

I have a website with https consider https://example.com which wants to call an API from an AWS EC2 instance consider http://ec2.##.##.##/get-users. I am getting Connection Refused when I do so but in POSTMAN it is working fine. Is this an issue with my AWS Security Group? and How to solve it?

Comment: Hi Rajat, please add more details.  Where are you running Postman from?  What are your security groups allowing and from where?  etc.

Comment: This should work fine. The problem could be security groups, NACLs, routing, internet gateway, something on-instance, or something else. We would need a _lot_ more information to work out what the problem.